# Vue Apexchart not showing negative value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to show the negative value in the chart, but its not showing, i tried so many configs but nothing is happening.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-apexcharts-using-datauri-forked-4t7cgz?file=/src/components/Chart.component.vue:469-958)

these are the true values.

the component:

```
<apexcharts
  ref="barchart"
  width="500"
  height="350"
  type="bar"
  :options="chartOptions"
  :series="series"
></apexcharts>
```

Options:

```
chartOptions: {
        colors: ["#00E676", "#9155FD", "#8A8D93"],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },

        xaxis: {
          categories: ["Janeiro", "Feb", "Mar"],
        },
  },
```

Series:

```
  series: [
    {
      name: "Receita",
      data: [241221.4, 277855.4],
    },
    {
      name: "Sub",
      data: [15957.8, 18169.15],
    },
    {
      name: "Rat",
      data: [-776.525, -322.625],
    },
  ],
```

Comment: HI, it's not working, but i add an option in my chart and help me to show the negative value: tooltip: { shared: true, },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show negative values in the ApexCharts chart, the `min` option in the `yaxis` configuration is set to a value less than 0. So with the `xaxis`, add this code:

```
yaxis: {
    min: -100
},
```

Comment: HI, it's not working, but i add an option in my chart and help me to show the negative value:

tooltip: {
          shared: true,
        },

Comment: Actually. Instead of providing a constant, this option also accepts a function: `(min) => value`, the min parameter provided by Apexcharts is the minimum data value, which is perfect. So just provide this to the `yaxis` option object: `min: (min) => min` and is till extend the area y axsis to negative values.

Answer (score 0):

I add these options in my chart and solved my problem to show the values:

```
legend: {
          position: "right",
          width: 128,
        },

 tooltip: {
          shared: true,
        },
```